# Microsoft Owin Self Host with performance counters hangs on exit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin, performancecounter

I have Owin self hosted web api app (without any controllers) on windows with performance counters inside and when I try to stop it (stop all my internal services, threads, dispose web host, etc) then it hangs for ~10 sec and then closes. There is no threads left in my app. It just waits ~10 sec and then exits.
If I remove performance counter logic OR web host creation - application is closed normally.

Nuget packages used:

```
Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1
Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.3.0.1
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.3.0.1
Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8
Owin.1.0
System.Net.Http
System.Net.Http.Formatting (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3)
System.Web.Http (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3)
System.Web.Http.Owin (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin.5.2.3)
```

.Net Framework used: v4.5

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    private static PerformanceCounter Counter;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var webHost = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://127.0.0.1:5000/"))
        {
            var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Thread Count", process.ProcessName, true);

            Console.WriteLine(Counter.NextValue());

            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Exit1");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Exit2"); // hangs after this
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.LocalOnly;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share a sample on github? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/AlexanderButs/WebApiWithPerfCounter

Comment: Tried this one. Didn't face any issues (tried debug/release mode, with or without debugger attached). Maybe it is your PC?

Comment: My colleague has the same issue. I checked this at home - the same result. Tried VS2012 and VS2015 community edition. Also tried framework v4.6 - the same result.

Comment: This issue is experienced only on Windows 7. We checked it on Win8 and Win10 - works good. Have You opportunity to check it on win7?